# can someone trace the reason for this race condition?

Tags: c++, atomic, race-condition

**c++ atomics** **race condition**
i am learning c++ atomics.so i have made a race condition intentionally.as you can see my void add function increment x by 1 prints the value of x and the thread name which incremented it. the two threads t1 and t2 have access to  void add function .so this is a race condition and i get output like 1,1 1,2(best case) 2,2 and 2,1. My question is how the 2,1 output is possible. anyone please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<atomic>


using namespace std;

int x = 0;
std::atomic<int>s{ 0 };

void add(const char* c) {
    ++x;
    cout<< c << endl << x << endl;
}

int main() {
    std::thread t1(add,"t1");
    std::thread t2(add,"t2");
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: There's a common misconception that "atomic" means "thread safe, and I can access this variable in any way I want in any thread and I will always get the result that I think is right". This is not true. P.S.: the shown code doesn't even use an atomic variable, it is completely unused.

Comment: @RichardCritten: That's not true, e.g. anytime the output of your process depends on the timing of some of its threads you have a race condition. That does not imply that the corresponding C++ program invokes undefined behavior. A race condition and a data race are NOT the same thing. An example: if I start two threads that both print their ID I have created a race condition but neither a data race nor undefined behavior.

Comment: @Peter see the quote from cppreference above - I will look for a The Standard Quote.

Comment: Your question confuses two unrelated issues. First, the code as written exhibits undefined behavior, by way of updating a non-atomic object `x` in two threads with no synchronization. Anything whatsoever is allowed to happen. Second, even if you replace `x` with `s` thus avoiding undefined behavior, the program is non-deterministic: thread `t1` can complete before `t2` starts, or `t2` can complete before `t1` starts, or the two may interleave (so e.g. one thread performs the increment, then the other performs the increment, then they print the same value `2`).

Comment: According to the C++ standard, yes, this is undefined behavior. In practice, the program behavior is likely defined by the used implementation (simply by non-atomic reads/writes). The problem is that you don't synchronize the use of `std::cout`, therefore, the effects of `<<` may be interleaved any way.

Answer (score 0):

Your question confuses two unrelated issues. First, the code as written exhibits undefined behavior, by way of updating a non-atomic object `x` in two threads with no synchronization. Anything whatsoever is allowed to happen; it's pointless to try to reason about a particular outcome.

Second, even if you replace `x` with `s` thus avoiding undefined behavior, the program is non-deterministic: thread `t1` can complete before `t2` starts, or `t2` can complete before `t1` starts, or the two may interleave (so e.g. one thread performs the increment, then the other performs the increment, then they print the same value `2`). The program can print `t1 1 t2 2` or `t2 1 t1 2` or `t1 2 t2 2` or even `t1 t2 2 1` - all these outcomes are consistent with one possible execution of the non-deterministic abstract machine defined by the program.